# How can I rollback Windows from 32-bit to 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I went to upgrade Windows 7 home (64-bit) version to Windows 7 Ultimate.

I downloaded the 32-bit OS instead of 64-bit. The program let me do it. 
It loaded, but I lost the functionality of all the programs loaded previously.

How can I rollback from 32-bit to 64-bit?

Comment: simply put, it can't be done....

Answer (score 8):

You cannot go from 32-bit to 64-bit or 64-bit to 32-bit without a complete reinstall. I suspect that when you did your "upgrade", you performed a complete reinstall, overwriting your 64-bit installation, and killing all your previously-installed programs.

The only other possibility is that maybe you somehow did the install to an empty partition, and the original partition remains untouched. This is EXTREMELY unlikely, but you can see if there are any other partitions in the Disk Manager.

Answer (score 2):

As far as my knowledge goes on the matter, you need to clean re-install Windows if you want to change from 32bit to 64bit. I had the problem and couldn't find a solution other than reinstalling everything, maybe someone else knows of a different solution, would be nice to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to upgrade (or 'downgrade') your Windows installation from 32-bit to 64-bit (or the other way around). Your only hope is a fresh installation, I believe you know how to do this.

Just a note, your 64-bit drivers and 64-bit applications they will not work on 32-bit Windows, but the 32-bit applications will work on 64-bit systems.